# SELECT posts and their comments

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have three tables: `users`, `posts`, and `comments`.

How do I `SELECT` the first three posts, each with their comment count and first three comments?

Example: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e4360/3)

*Goal is to build a table like the one below*

- The first row of each post_id grouping is the post
- The comment_id is that post's comment count
- The next rows are the first three comments for that post

**Expected output:**

```
-- post_id   comment_id   user_id   body               created_at
-- 1         4            1         Hello. I'm Jane.   August, 28 2016 14:12:01
-- 1         1            2         Nice post, Jane.   August, 28 2016 14:12:01
-- 1         2            1         Thank you, John.   August, 28 2016 14:12:01
-- 1         3            2         You're welcome.    August, 28 2016 14:12:01
-- 2         2            1         This is post 2.    August, 28 2016 14:12:01
-- 2         5            2         I like this.       August, 28 2016 14:12:01
-- 2         6            1         Why, thank you.    August, 28 2016 14:12:01
-- 3         0            1         This is post 3.    August, 28 2016 14:12:01
```

Comment: Do you mean the first three posts period, or the first three posts for each user ?  And better to put table schema in the post here on SO as well as in a link...

Comment: That is, the output should be 9 rows ? post1-comm1, post1-comm2, post1-comm3, post2-comm1, ...

Comment: @CharlesBretana I meant the first three posts period. I actually do want to get the first three posts for a specified (not for each) user. But, I left that part out because I wanted to simplify my question, and I figured I'd know how to modify the query to work for the posts of a specific user rather than all the posts.

Comment: @Mike no, the output could be anywhere from 0 to 12 rows. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39192948/242933 for an understanding of the expected output.

Comment: "I meant the first three posts period. I actually do want to get the first three posts for a specified (not for each) user".  Those are exactly the two different options I am asking you to choose between.  The first three posts period would be across the setoff all posts from all users.  I think you want the first three posts for each user, (or for a specified user)

Comment: @CharlesBretana in actuality, I want the first three posts for a specific user, e.g., `WHERE user_id=1`. For simplicity, however, I omitted that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Understanding the logic behind the expected output**

You have a pretty sophisticated demand for your expected output. From what I understood from your *sql fiddle* looking at expected result, you want to:

1. get first three posts
2. get first three comments for them
3. append the result from 1 and 2 with different logic for columns `comment_id` and `body`

The difference in logic seems to be like below:

For each row representing a **post**:

- in `comment_id` store number of comments for that post
- in `user_id` store the user that wrote a post
- in `body` store the body of the post
- in `created_at` store the timestamp when the post was created

While for each row representing **comment** the logic is analogical (but for a comment, not a post) with the exception of `comment_id` column where you want to store the comment `id`.

**Query and explanation**

*For live example look at **[SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/567f2f/1)***

First, take first three posts and build rows for them counting comments for each one. Then, union those posts rows with comment rows, and use `row_number()` function to limit comment rows in the output to maximum of 3 per a post.

Assigning `0` as row number for posts means they fulfill the condition of `rn <= 3`.

To order the output as you wish so that for every post their comments are sorted right after them I've added an `order_column` to be able to include it in `ORDER BY`.

```
WITH first_posts AS (
    SELECT p.id AS post_id, COUNT(c.id) AS comment_id, p.user_id, p.body, p.created_at
    FROM (SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id LIMIT 3) AS p
    LEFT JOIN comments AS c
    ON p.id = c.post_id
    GROUP BY 1, 3, 4, 5
)
SELECT post_id, comment_id, user_id, body, created_at
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS type, post_id, comment_id, user_id, body, created_at, 0 AS r
    FROM first_posts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS type, p.post_id, c.id, c.user_id, c.body, c.created_at, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.post_id ORDER BY c.id) AS r
    FROM first_posts AS p
    INNER JOIN comments AS c
    ON p.post_id = c.post_id
    ORDER BY post_id, type, comment_id
) AS f
WHERE r <= 3;
```

Comment: Yes, you understand the logic of the output I want—Although, I'm not sure if the output I want is actually a good idea (too clever?) or if there's a better way to get all the data I want.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid output, but would look better if you indicated which row contains information about post and which about comment. This could be easily done by adding one more column just like I did with `order_column`. Why you want the output like that is a different question. I'm not familiar with your needs and projects.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Are the comment counts guaranteed to be correct even if someone inserts a comment in the middle of this query, i.e., if there's a race condition?

Comment: Everything depends on your [transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) level. __Read committed__ is the default one meaning that you obtain a snapshot of database with the data committed before the query began.

Comment: OK. So if the transaction isolation level is read committed, then the (outputted) comment counts will always be in sync with the (outputted) comments?

Comment: Yes, exactly at the time the query started.

Comment: OK. Thank you. :-) Thank you for your answer by the way. It looks great and answers my question exactly. How could I modify the query to get the *last* (not first) three comments ordered by comment_id (ascending)?

Comment: They are already ordered ascending. In the `ROW_NUMBER`s order by clause add `DESC` after `ORDER BY c.id` to reverse sorting order. This will fetch 3 last comments instead of first.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with further exploration -)

Comment: Thank you. :-) Good luck & best wishes to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to limit your selection to the first 3 posts and `row_number` to only include the first 3 comments per post:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.post_id ORDER BY c.id) rn
    FROM posts p
    JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
    WHERE p.id IN (SELECT id FROM posts ORDER BY id LIMIT 3)
) t WHERE rn <= 3
```

or if you want the first 3 posts & comments per user

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.post_id ORDER BY c.id) comments_rn,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.user_id ORDER BY p.id) post_rn        
    FROM posts p
    JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
    JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id
) t WHERE comments_rn <= 3 and post_rn <= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

edited Syntax and column names:

```
Select id, name, p.*, c.* 
from users u
    join posts p on p.User_Id = u.Id
       and (Select count(*) From posts 
            where user_Id = u.Id
               and created_at <= p.created_at) <= 3
    join comments c on c.post_Id = p.Id
       and (Select count(*) From comments 
            where post_Id = p.Id 
               and created_at <= c.created_at) <= 3
```

Comment: It should be `user_id` instead of `userId`. The same with `postId`. Also, users table has no `user_id` column etc...

Comment: This is why you should put table schema in the post, not only in a link,....  And are you actually complaining because you need to edit the sql a bit?

Comment: Would you mind looking at the username of the person asking question and mine? Bravo!

Comment: My apologies to the OP,  I missed that.  And, if you are only correcting the syntax for OPs benefit, not criticizing my answer for not being perfect, my apologies to you as well.

Comment: Well, then, you are exactly as correct as I would hope you to be, sir.  As I imagine you are aware, it's frustrating to spend time and effort trying to help someone solve a problem, only to be criticized for something trivial or not germane.  But jumping to unwarranted conclusions without all the facts can be embarrassing.